# Shell script command returned an unwanted single quote

Tags: shell

I am currently developing a shell script to run dbsat report for Oracle 19c pluggable database(not CDB)

I’ve tried this command ==>

```bash
CMD=$($usrAppDir/dbsat collect -n '"/ as sysdba"'@${PDB} $usrAppWrkDir > /dev/null 2>&1) >> $sSLog
```

But get the wrong output with an extra unwanted single quote ==>

```bash
/home/oracle/dbsat/dbsat collect -n '"/ as sysdba"@T270' /home/oracle/dbsat/T270_pdcexa0vm02clu03_collect_20221214
```

How can I get the right output I need ==>

```
/home/oracle/dbsat/dbsat collect -n "/ as sysdba"@T270 /home/oracle/dbsat/T270_pdcexa0vm02clu03_collect_20221214
```

I am struggling with this, not sure why this command returned an unwanted single quote `'"/ as sysdba"@T270'`

Wondering if you could give me any advice?

Thanks a lot in advance.

===================
p.s.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

ls -l /bin/sh

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Apr 30  2022 /bin/sh -> bash
```

==================

Kind Regards

Anne

I tried `\`, like ==> `\"/ as sysdba\"`, but it made things worse.

Comment: I think this issue is related to oracle dbsat script, it will generate single quotes ‘ ‘ if there is connection string like @{PDB} after ./dbsat collect “/ as sysdba”. So it only can generate report in CDB level.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in the script => `export ORACLE_PDB_SID={PDB}`
then it's working properly.

Comment: Good job with the follow-through and answering your own question. You can offset text as fixed-width by surrounding it with `\`\`\`` (3 backticks) inline. Are you sure that shouldn't be `export ORACLE_PDB_SID="${PDB}"`?